# Quarkus Project - vertx-blocked-thread-checker

Tags: hibernate, quarkus-panache, quarkus-rest-client

WARN  [io.ver.cor.imp.BlockedThreadChecker] (vertx-blocked-thread-checker) Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-4,5,main] has been blocked for 3912 ms,

I need help with this WARNING

Answer (score 0):

This warning is issued when a Vert.x managed thread is blocked by a task during too much time (the default limit is 2000 ms).

This is a problem because Vert.x is using internally the event loop pattern. And code that runs on event loops should not per­form block­ing I/O or lengthy pro­cess­ing (see [Eclipse Vert.x and reactive in just a few words](https://vertx.io/introduction-to-vertx-and-reactive/) for more information). In your case Vert.x detected it took at least 3912 ms.

I do not know what you are doing in your case, but consider :

- using only non-blocking API (such as reactive HTTP client) if it is the problem and if it is possible,
- or running your code in a worker thread by calling Vert.x `executeBlocking` method (see [Running blocking code](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code) in Vert.x documentation for more information).

You can also increase Vert.x configuration property [blockedThreadCheckInterval](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/VertxOptions.html#setBlockedThreadCheckInterval-long-) but that not recommended.